# $5$ conditions with $|A| = a , |B| = b , |A \cap B| = c$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

$5$ conditions with $|A| = a , |B| = b , |A \cap B| = c$

Find the following:

> 1: Number of subsets of $A$ that aren't subsets of $B$.
>
> 2: Number of subsets of $B$ that don't contain any element of group $A$
>
> 3: Number of subsets of $A \oplus B$
>
> 4: Given $x \in A-B$, $y \in B-A$, how many subsets of $A\oplus B$ contain $x$ and do not contain $y$.
>
> 5: How many options do we have to arrange elements of $A\oplus B$ in line where $x,y$ are not adjacent.

**My opinions:**

I drew a Venn diagram for $A,B$ and I called it $1,2,3,4$
[image]

> 1: I need to find $P(A-B)$, thus, $2^a - 2^c$.
>
> 2: need to find $P(B-A)$, thus, $2^b - 2^c$.
>
> 3: need to find $P(A\oplus B)$ thus, $2^{a+b-2c}$
>
> 4: need to find $A\oplus B - (B-A)$ thus again $2^a - 2^c$ (The answer is based on how many we contain x,y (both) and subtracting those that just do not contain y)
>
> 5: All possibilities arranging in line are : $(a+b-2c)!$, now I need to subtract with all the possibilities $x,y$ are adjacent. which means I put $x$ on odd places and $y$ on even places. and we need to arrange them in their spots on that line, so it is $(a-c)! * (b-c)!$ thus, $(a+b-2c)! - (a-c)! * (b-c)!$ would be my answer. (maybe I need to divide by $2!$? because I can put $x$ on even and $y$ on odd places.)

I'm sorry in advance if it is not allowed to ask so many questions in one post, I don't know otherwise how to ask all these. I hope you can assist me in answering them. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Correct.
2. $|\mathcal P \left({B-(A\cap B)}\right)| = 2^{b-c}$.
3. Correct.
4. We need the number of subsets of set $A\oplus B - \{x,y\}$ because for each one we add element $x$ to get one of the required subsets. Therefore, the answer is,

$$|\mathcal P \left({A\oplus B - \{x,y\}}\right)| = 2^{a+b-2c-2}.$$

5. As you say, there are $(a+b-2c)!$ total arrangements. Counting those where a given $x,y$ are adjacent, there are $a+b-2c-1$ possible positions for an adjacent pair in a string of length $a+b-2c$ and $2$ ways to arrange $x$ and $y$ within each of those positions. In each case, there are $(a+b-2c-2)!$ ways to arrange all the other elements. Therefore, the number of arrangements with $x,y$ adjacent is $2(a+b-2c-1)(a+b-2c-2)! = 2(a+b-2c-1)!$. So the answer is

$$(a+b-2c)! - 2(a+b-2c-1)!$$

Comment: I didn't understand what you wrote about answer (4.) Any chance you can explain a bit better? Thanks!

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS We have set $A\oplus B - \{x,y\}$. Suppose we take any subset of that set. Then we add element $x$ to it. Then we have a subset of $A\oplus B$ that contains $x$ but not $y$.

Example: Say $A=\{a,b,c\}$ and $B=\{c,d,e\}$ with $x=a$ and $y=e$. Then $A\oplus B - \{x,y\} = \{b,d\}$. All its subsets are: $\{\},\;\{b\},\;\{d\},\;\{b,d\}$.
To each one, add $a$, giving $\{a\},\;\{a,b\},\;\{a,d\},\;\{a,b,d\}$. These are exactly the subsets we require.

Comment: Wow! Thats awesome! Thank you sir. !!!